# What's the best way to find the user's Documents directory on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm reading Erica Sadun's *iPhone Developer's Cookbook*, and ran into a question.

She says in the book that the way to find the user's Documents directory is with the code:

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

but that seems slightly brittle, and dissimiliar to the normal Mac way of doing it, which would be:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Are there any particular reasons to use one over the other?

Comment: typo: NSDocumentsDirectory ==> NSDocumentDirectory

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Objc:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
```

Swift:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
```

You'll want the first element of the returned array.

Comment: Cool, that's what I'll use, but why it and not the other way?

Comment: You can use the other way, but if an upgrade to the OS changes the default structure, this answer is guaranteed to still work with the new layout while the first way will either fail or start re-creating legacy directories.

Answer (score 50):

Here is the code that I use in my framework.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Since Xcode 5, you should use `[paths firstObject]` instead of `[paths objectAtIndex:0]`.

Comment: Or "NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];"

Comment: Or `paths.firstObject` since it's a `property`.

Answer (score 16):

#### You should consider using the FileManager methods which return URLs, which are the preferred format.

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

This method is intended to locate known and common directories in the system.

An array of URL objects identifying the requested directories. The directories are ordered according to the order of the domain mask constants, with items in the user domain first and items in the system domain last.

Comment: That is right. Our knowledge should be upgraded that in iOS we should use NSURL, rather than NSString (for path) to represent local file.

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *zipLocalPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingString:fileName];
```

Answer (score -1):

In swift v3, I used the following snippet

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
```