# Cross-platform way to ask for the user's documents folder?

Tags: java, cross-platform

I'm writing a cross-platform program in Java and want to stick the configuration files in the user's documents folder ("My Documents" under Windows, "Documents" under appropriate Linux, and whatever the folder's called under Mac OS), but I'm not sure how to ask Java for that.

I'd like to stay away from hard-coding things (do *X* if we're on Windows, *Y* if we're on Linux, or *Z* if we're on OS X), as this puts the burden of support on my shoulders rather than the Oracle development team.

I've checked the system properties list, but it doesn't seem to include the user's documents folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly there is no easy cross-platform way.  You will have to take advantage of native functionality on each OS platform

- Here is some info on how to do it in [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567874/how-do-i-find-the-users-documents-folder-with-java-in-os-x)
- Here is some info on how to do it in [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java)

For Linux I don't have a convenient link, but given that there isn't necessarily the concept of a Documents folder in Linux, I don't know of a good solution.  The system property `user.home` should at least be valid in Linux.

Comment: Do you think I'd be able to get away with a few short lines of code per OS? Reading some of the answers at least for the Windows link you have there makes me think you have to use lots and lots of code to do something that seems like it should be rather easy.

Comment: One of those links I think had a link to a library on google code to do it for you (for Windows).  So at least you personally would not have to write much code to call it.  I'm not sure what you consider lots and lots of code, but at least this is the sort of things where you do it one time and then you can use it for all projects you ever do, so it has a lot of value.

Comment: "_seems like it should be rather easy..._"  This doesn't seem like something that should be easy... Considering that every flavor of every OS can put the user's "_documents_" directory wherever it wants.  Not to mention that not every OS **has** a documents directory.  Heck... Users don't even need to have a home directory on every OS, do they?

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution:

boolean isMac = System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X");

Or use http://commons.apache.org/vfs/ to get the operating system:
http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/util/Os.html

// the folder name is the same whatever the language of Mac OSX.

Mac: System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Documents");

/Users/david/Documents

Win: System.getenv("APPDATA"));

C:\Documents and Settings\david\Application Data

Answer (score 1):

*Ask* the user, somehow, where they want to save data to, or use the current directory (simple relative paths) and provide appropriate instructions for set up.  One means of "asking" is having a property that can be set via the command line.

Don't just pollute the user's home directory with your application's stuff - how do you know how they like their document tree organized?

I am absolutely fed up with *nix oriented programs dropping their little config files and data folders into the root of my documents folder.

Comment: One of the programs I'm modelling my application after is the Arduino development tool, and it just drops its files in $HOME/sketchbook.
http://ardiuno.cc/

Answer (score 1):

This is usually not possible in a generic way. You will have to use platform dependent apstractions. I do it like this for AppData e.g., on Windows I detect the AppData/Roaming or AppData/Local, depending on the data I need to store, on other Platforms I create a folder ".myappname" in the userhome, and use this.

For the documents folder, you will have to read the registry. Before Windows Vista using the user.home propery + "/Documents" is not enought, because in other languages it might be "/Dokumente" (german) or something else. Just the registry has the real path to this folder.

On linux platforms it depends on the Desktop environment. You will just have to try it out. Gnome and KDE use different places to store the Documents folder, IMHO. And if you just use FVWM there, there is no predefined place for docs except the user.home property, what is a good fallback.

Comment: How would I query the registry?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an application which requires installation, Why not ask the user to specify the location during installation. Generate a run script using this information which would set the appropriate environment variables. As a norm the user is not expected to run the `java` command!

When the user starts the application using this run script, the application can read the environment variables.

Alternatively, create a jar file with configuration files. Read the config files using Classloader's getResourceAsStream. As long as the configuration jar is under the classpath you can access the files. This also has the added advantage of hiding the configuration from accidental modification. This should work for folders as well (if the config needs to be modified by the user).

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a second .jar file with the configuration data or appending the configuration data to the "master" .jar file?

Comment: All I mean was to have it in a resource which is part of CLASSPATH :)

Answer (score -2):

What is wrong with hardcoding a way to get the path depending on the users operating system?
There can be large variances and OS's work differently with different names.
Simply on launch find the path of the documents folder based on their OS and continue to reference that path wherever it is needed.

Comment: The problem is that the variety of operating system versions often have different paths, and localization can affect it as well.  The only correct way is to use the native functionality provided by the OS on the given platform.

Comment: Hard coding the path is an awful idea, mostly because it isn't the same even by the same operating system. As Justin pointed out, localization may be an issue, Roaming Profiles is another common reason. Also, the user can change it. In Windows 7, just right click on your "My Documents" folder (not the Library, the actual folder), and change it on the Location tab.

Comment: I am refering to hardcoding a way to decern each operating system.

Comment: That isn't really hard coding then, it's just writing a function. As Justin pointed out, most operating systems have "hard coded" this for you in their API specification.

Comment: Unless you know all translations that could be used there is no general way to do this. At least on Linux "Documents" folder can be translated in any langauge and user can even select if he want to keep folders is English language or in whatever other language he/she is using...  Which is why I was looking for some more generic way... But it seems there is not any...