# How to save data from version to version in iphone app development?

Tags: ios, iphone, persistence

I'm having a problem for my app, a Chinese-English dictionary. I'm now adding a wordbook for it, and try to save the contents of it to a plist every time users exit the app. But now I find that as my app updates, all these data will get lost because the path of the app is changed.

I'm now working for a company so the app will keep releasing new versions, and how can I save the data from version to version?

Comment: Depending on the size and complexity of the wordbook, it might be better to let Core Data manage your data: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Answer (score 2):

*all these data will get lost because the path of the app is changed.*

That would indicate you're writing to your application's directory structure.  Don't do that.

The iPhone has a documents directory.

[Document Directory discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone)

Comment: well I'm just using the following code to get the path 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; with these code I can get the path in the NSString documentsDirectory like "var/moblie/Applications/***/Documents". But my problem is that every time when I reinstall the app(or install a new version), the "***" part will be changed to another randomized string. That's why I said the path of the app is changed. thx anyway.

Comment: That may be true, but as it changes, the contents of the directory are copied along with it, so it should still be in that directory.