# Best way to handle offline storage in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

In my app in iPhone getting data from server through web services. When no internet connection is there on my device, it will get the data from localstorage. Suggest the best way to handle offline storage in iPhone app?

Sri

Comment: What sort of stuff are you storing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep local copies of your data in the app's [Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone).