# Is there an editor for inserting/editing rows into a Core Data DB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios

I've created a Core Data schema in xcode (3.2.5 if it matters) so I have the .xcdatamodel file with the proper entities and relations.

Now - How can I insert data, edit data and/or delete data from it, NOT from within the code ?
Like what phpMyAdmin is for MySql.

Thanks.

Comment: When you look at the Documents directory of an iPhone app, there is an SQL-file. I have never tried, but maybe you can edit the file.

Comment: Couldn't find and Documents directory in the xcode project directory, nor could I find any sql(lite) file, and I checked every file in there (using linux "file" command).

Comment: it's in the App's folder. If your running from the simulator, the folder is somewhere /Users/-yourname-/Library/Application Support/iOS Simulator/User/Applications/... You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Data is meant to be used programmatically.  Once you run the app once, it should create a file somewhere on disk (exactly where is probably specified in the AppDelegate class).  It is *likely* that this file will be a SQLite database, but it doesn't have to be (the point of Core Data is to abstract your data away from the file format used to store it).  It could also be an XML file or a binary file.

If it's a SQLite file, then you can open it in your favorite SQLite editor.

## HOWEVER

The schema used in the SQLite format is not documented.  If you go mucking around in it, you might get stuff to work, but it's also very likely that you could irreparably screw it up.  (If it's an XML file or a binary file, you're probably totally out of luck)

In the end, Core Data is *supposed* to be used programmatically.  To use it in a different way (such as what you're asking for) would be to use it in a way for which it was not intended and therefore not designed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already solved your problem, but there's this SQLite Manager plug-in for firefox: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/
I haven't tried importing data or using the INSERT command to insert individual rows, but you could give it a try. It's free and works very well for me as is.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few database management tools available for sqlite that allow you to do this. I've tried a few but to be honest none of them have impressed me that much as yet.

Would be great to have something like Toad available.

Anyway, find wherever your database file is, then drop it onto whichever application.

You can then add, delete, and edit rows and columns.

Of course, you will need to maintain any foreign keys and such like.

I find the generated Core Data models to be pretty easy to understand.

Example tools are SQLite Database Browser (free), SQLiteManager (not free), and Base. A quick Google search should reveal those and a few more.

I normally use SQLite Database Browser although it does crash occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

See Christian Kienle's [Core data editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/). It's not free, but is designed to work directly with core data models and stores via Apple's API, supports binary data, builds relationships  and even triggers validation, etc. I've found it's worth the $20.