# objective-c simple nsarray writeToFile issue

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, writetofile

```
[wordlist writeToFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathForResource:@"wordlist" ofType:@"txt"] atomically: YES];
```

wordlist is a NSMutableArray, and the rest you know what.

The problem is that nothing is saved in wordlist.txt when I run the codes in Xcode. In front of this code nslog shows that there are 4 objects in wordlist. How come?

---

Edit:
Right!

These codes work!:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourArrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wordlist.txt"];  
[wordlist writeToFile:yourArrayFileName atomically:YES];    
NSLog (@"%@", yourArrayFileName);
```

---

Edit 29 august 2011.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/YOURNAME/Desktop/";
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"norsk.txt"];

    NSString *content = @"æ ø å";
    BOOL ok = [content writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"Error writing file !");
    }
```

also works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write in you app's bundle.

You need to write in the user's directory. You can know more about it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone).

There's three directory you can write in

- NSDocumentDirectory : the document directory. The user will be able to see these file. This should be for user files only. Backed up by iTunes.
- NSCachesDirectory : the cache directory is where you place things you app may need in the future, but that you can reconstruct. Not backed up by iTunes.
- NSApplicationSupportDirectory : the application support is where you place your essential files for your application. Backed up by iTunes.